# Unsupported operation: References cannot be parsed

Tags: dart, petitparser

```
static const String tabChar = '\u0009';
Parser tab() => ref(token, tabChar);
```

```
expect(tab().accept(tabChar), isTrue);
```

with the `token` method from https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser/blob/ddd9921d702dd18cda4e2f84190777b7dc20b3e2/example/dart/src/grammar.dart (with the default `trim` parser)

What needs to be changed to get rid of the error?

> Unsupported operation: References cannot be parsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unresolved references in your parser graph, you need to resolve them before you can parse an input.

Your example code lacks context to tell exactly what is going wrong. If you subclass `GrammarDefinition` and call `build()` on the definition the resulting parser has all references resolved. Have a look at the documentation in [GrammarDefinition](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser/blob/ddd9921d702dd18cda4e2f84190777b7dc20b3e2/lib/src/core/definition/grammar.dart#L68) and check out how the `DartGrammarDefinition` is used from [its tests](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser/blob/ddd9921d702dd18cda4e2f84190777b7dc20b3e2/test/dart_test.dart#L9).

Comment: That is helpful. I completely missed the `build()` method and the dart_test.test. That was already quite helpful. Thanks a lot.